# ¿Cómo cambiar @import por @use al customisar un framework css?

Tags: html, css, nodejs, sass, bulma

Estoy intentando cambiar los `@import` de esta hoja de estilo.scss por `@use` **excepto el "@import url(..fonts..)".**
La siguiente hoja.scss es de la documentaión de `BULMA`, de la parte de customize con with  Sass CLI; lo importante es que al cambiar el `@import` por `@use` y ponerlo al inicio del archivo como se sugiere, me sale un error, como muestro más abajo.

```
@charset "utf-8";

// Import a Google Font
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700');

// Set your brand colors
$purple: #8A4D76;
$pink: #FA7C91;
$brown: #757763;
$beige-light: #D0D1CD;
$beige-lighter: #EFF0EB;

// Update Bulma's global variables
$family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$grey-dark: $brown;
$grey-light: $beige-light;
$primary: $purple;
$link: $pink;
$widescreen-enabled: false;
$fullhd-enabled: false;

// Update some of Bulma's component variables
$body-background-color: $beige-lighter;
$control-border-width: 2px;
$input-border-color: transparent;
$input-shadow: none;

// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import "../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@import "../bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";

    // Import only what you need from Bulma
@use "../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";
```

En el siguiente archivo solo se pone los `@use` al inicio:

```
    // Import only what you need from Bulma
@use "../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/button.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/container.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/title.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/form/_all.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass";
@use "../bulma/sass/layout/section.sass";


@charset "utf-8";

// Import a Google Font
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,700');

// Set your brand colors
$purple: #8A4D76;
$pink: #FA7C91;
$brown: #757763;
$beige-light: #D0D1CD;
$beige-lighter: #EFF0EB;

// Update Bulma's global variables
$family-sans-serif: "Nunito", sans-serif;
$grey-dark: $brown;
$grey-light: $beige-light;
$primary: $purple;
$link: $pink;
$widescreen-enabled: false;
$fullhd-enabled: false;

// Update some of Bulma's component variables
$body-background-color: $beige-lighter;
$control-border-width: 2px;
$input-border-color: transparent;
$input-shadow: none;
```

**Y me sale el siguiente error en la terminal:**

```
Error: There's already a module with namespace "all".
  ╷
3 │ @use "../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass";
  │ ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ original @use
4 │ @use "../bulma/sass/base/_all.sass";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ new @use
  ╵
  src\sass\custome.scss 4:1  root stylesheet
```

**NOTA:** estoy usando `sass` en `windown` con `Chocolatey`.

Answer (score 1):

El método `@use` a diferencia del clásico `@import`, maneja los estilos importados como módulos, especificando un namespace con el parámetro `as _nombre_`, cuando no se especifica un namespace por defecto lo define el nombre de archivo (p.e. `_all` => `all`), como hay más de un archivo con el mismo nombre salta el error que se indicas.

Para eliminar los namespaces y que `@use` funcione como `@import`, agrega el comodín `as *` a tus imports.

```scss
@use "../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/base/_all.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/button.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/container.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/elements/title.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/form/_all.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass" as *;
@use "../bulma/sass/layout/section.sass" as *;
```

Comment: +1, además otra alternativa es usar `@use "path/file.sass" as <namespace>;` donde `<namespace>` puede ser cualquier letra/palabra. [Más info](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace)

Answer (score 0):

aplicando lo que recomienda la respuesta de **@Vlady** sale el siguiente error:

```
    Error: This variable is available from multiple global modules.
╷
2   │     @use "../bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes va
riable
3   │     @use "../bulma/sass/base/_all.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
4   │     @use "../bulma/sass/elements/button.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
5   │     @use "../bulma/sass/elements/container.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
6   │     @use "../bulma/sass/elements/title.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
7   │     @use "../bulma/sass/form/_all.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
8   │     @use "../bulma/sass/components/navbar.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
9   │     @use "../bulma/sass/layout/hero.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
10  │     @use "../bulma/sass/layout/section.sass" as *;
│     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ includes variable
... │
18  │     $purple: #8A4D76;
│     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ variable use
╵
  src\sass\custome.scss 18:5  root stylesheet
```

**No se como esta escrito BULMA;** creo que mejor mandare los `@import` a una nueva _hoja.scss y luego lo llamare con `@use`.